# Best way to set a dynamic frame for all devices

Tags: swiftui

What is the best way to avoid hardcoding a .frame

`.frame(width: 200, height: 200)`

and make the view dynamic and responsive to all screen sizes. My question is specific for iOS devices.

I'm sure there you guys do not need any code to answer this question but just to make things clear, here is an example. I'd like to make this `Rectangle()` dynamic to all screen sizes.

```
import SwiftUI

struct VideoPlayerView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
    }
}

struct VideoPlayerView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        VideoPlayerView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `GeometryReader` to get view dimensions. Here is an example:

```
struct VideoPlayerView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { g in
            Rectangle()
                .frame(width: g.size.width / 2, height: g.size. height / 2)
        }
    }
}
```